# Prevent the onClick on ReactJS if the div contains a specific id

Tags: reactjs

I have a wrapper that has an on-click but I want that to work only if it clicked within a specific child div or more exactly the first div, but I don't know how to do that.

[image: jsxmaster]

Here for example:

```
<div onClick={() => openMenu()}> // this opens and closes menu
     <div>
       Menu
     </div>

     <div> // this is hidden then later when openMenu&&true it shows
       Menu Dropdown and its content
     </div>
<div>
```

So what I want to do is when I click the first child Menu Item to call the function but when the second child is clicked it will not called.

Comment: Why don't you put the onClick on the child `div`?

Comment: Because is a menu wrapper, and thats the best place it works

Comment: Please post the actual code, not screenshots. And what you have shown does not show the problem that is in the title of your question.

Comment: Maybe you can check if `event.target` is the desired `div`?

Answer (score 0):

Set the div element on data-id.
And looking for this attr in the event.
For example:

```
const handleNormalMenu = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.dataset.id)
}
<div data-id={id} onClick={handleNormalMenu}></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't make that much sense can you explain?, is this at the parent item or child, if is parent then that wont work

Comment: @recabos710 Cast the event simply to a child element, or show more code. I m don't understand what do u want.